# PHP. Zend DB adapter

Tags: php, sorting, zend-framework, zend-db-select

There is gallery on my site, and every picture has own tag. All of the tags are sorting chaotically. I want to sort them by value of field "index" in galleryTagsTable.

When it's show chaotically code was:

```
foreach ($_tags as $item) {
    $select = new Select();
    $tags[] = $this->getGalleryTagsTable()->fetchAll($select->where(array('id' => $item)));
}
```

To make sorting by field "index", I created this field and wrote this code:

```
foreach ($_tags as $item) {
    $select = new Select();
    $tags[] = $this->getGalleryTagsTable()->fetchAll($select->where(array('id' => $item))->order('index DESC'));
}
```

but it still doesn't work. I tried to write without 'DESC' & tried to sort by 'id'. None of these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your Select() object is some kind of extended object of Zend_Db_Select, I think this is not working as you expected because that's not the correct syntax for the where clause. Correct one would be:

```
$select->where('id = ?', $item)
       ->order('index DESC');
```

Note the '?' wildcard on the expression. This is made in case you don't want it to be an equals but a greater than, or other comparison clauses such as RLIKE. And please, note also that it's not an array.

Probably your where clause wasn't working as intended and that was causing the problems on the order of your tags since they were not grouped by id.

I hope this helps.